# Problems with OpenGL when running QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, opengl-es

I am trying to run basic examples of OpenGL using QT Creator to give color to a window. However, I am getting error in the compilation when calling the OpenGL instruction:
glClearColor(1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);
The *.pro file is the next:

```
QT       += core gui opengl
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = test2
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    glwidget.cpp
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    glwidget.h
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

The glwidget.h is the next:

```
#ifndef GLWIDGET_H
#define GLWIDGET_H
#include <QGLWidget>
class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void initializeGL();    
};
#endif // GLWIDGET_H
```

The glwidget.cpp is the next:

```
#include "glwidget.h"
GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QGLWidget(parent)
{
}
void GLWidget::initializeGL(){
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

The main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I have checked that in the *.pro I have included opengl:
QT       += core gui opengl
In addition, I have deleted the "YourProjectName-build-desktop" folder created by QT Creator and build again without success.

The error is:
C:\test2\glwidget.cpp:9: error: undefined reference to `_imp__glClearColor@16'
where line 9 is glClearColor(1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);

Which extra step I am missing?

Thank you in advance for your help

Cheers
© 2016 Microsoft Terms Privacy & cookies Developers English (United States)

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: I am getting C:\test2\glwidget.cpp:9: error: undefined reference to `_imp__glClearColor@16' where line 9 is glClearColor(1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try adding `LIBS += -lOpengl32` to .pro file

and if you`re using qt 5 you might as well take this route

```
QOpenGLFunctions *f = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->functions();
f->glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglcontext.html

**EDIT:**

just tested this an it works. but requires qt5.
Legacy functions seem to be defined in qt 5 so i left out QOpenGLFunctions.

```
#include <QOpenGLWidget>

class GLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget
{
public:
    GLWidget(QWidget* parent) :
        QOpenGLWidget(parent)
    {

    }

protected:
    void initializeGL()
    {
        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    void paintGL()
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glColor3f(1,0,0);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0);
        glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, 0);
        glVertex3f( 0.0, 0.5, 0);
        glEnd();
    }

    void resizeGL(int w, int h)
    {
        glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked for initializeGL. After this function I have the paintGL function (I didn't post) which includes:
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0);
        glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, 0);
        glVertex3f( 0.0,  0.5, 0);
    glEnd()
I have applied the same change, but didn't work.

Comment: @ArturoReyesLopez i add some test code that requires qt 5 though

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but I still found it. There is a more cross platform method (with Qt6 at least)

As seen in the official example here https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/opengl/hellogl2/glwidget.h?h=6.6 you can just inherit your class from QOpenGLFunctions:
`class YourGLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions`

`QOpenGLFunctions` provides a wrapper around opengl functions and does the linking for you. You also need to call `initializeOpenGLFunctions();` from `initializeGL()`, then you can use `glClearColor` or other opengl functions